# Searching for "motorway_junction" points with geolocation data and creating a config file with description (awk)

Tags: awk

I’m preparing a configuration file for navigation software. I need a list of activ motorway_junction points with their names, milestones (if present) and exits (if present).

I think, with awk is that possible.

It should be a following output-structure:

```
IDX,X,Y,TYPE,SPEED,DirType,Direction // $TYPE=“|milestone| name | exit_to“
```

the example node in the input-file from openstreetmap has a structure:

```
<node id="146994270" version="12" timestamp="2016-09-13T14:08:42Z" lat="50.4589679" lon="18.2668417">
<tag k="name" v="Kędzierzyn-Koźle"/>
<tag k="highway" v="motorway_junction"/>
<tag k="milestone" v="272"/> 
</node>
```

the script must search for nodes with tag

```
<tag k="highway" v="motorway_junction"/>
```

IF found, than read the following values in this node:

- lon → X
- lat → Y
- id → TYPE
- name value → Description
- exit_to value → Description
- milestones value → Description

Hint: not all  motorway_junction nodes have value milestones,  name or exit_to

The script should have the variables

- $IDX= → 0
- $SPEED= → 60
- $DirType= → 1
- $Direction= → 1

the „wish-output“ in this case:

```
0,18.2668417,50.4589679,146994270,60,1,1 // $146994270=“|272| Kędzierzyn-Koźle“
```

another example with exit_to

```
"Note: I'm not really sure where SPEED, $DirType, and $Driection are supposed to come from?"
```

Simply manually, the values are required, but the will not be showed.

"Also, in your expected output you don't use the exit_to value."
In the reality are motorway_junction points exits itself, but sometime the are more exits on this one point. A better example:

```
<node id="254705885" version="18" timestamp="2018-10-02T15:30:49Z" lat="53.3416624" lon="14.4562602">
<tag k="name" v="Szczecin Zachód"/>
<tag k="exit_to" v="Kołbaskowo;Szczecin;Rosówek;Schwedt"/>
<tag k="highway" v="motorway_junction"/>
</node>
```

expected output with exit_to (but here is milestone tag "empty")

```
0,14.4562602,53.3416624,254705885,60,1,1 // $254705885=“Szczecin Zachód | Kołbaskowo;Szczecin;Rosówek;Schwedt“
```

later, in the second step comes the text variable as formated text on the shield:
https://vk.com/@bydmapl-motorwayjunction

Answer (score 0):

This is not `awk` but the data you work with looks like a perfect match for an `HTML` parser like `BeautifulSoup`.

Here's my take on your task written in `Python3`.

Note: I'm not really sure where `SPEED`, `$DirType`, and `$Driection` are supposed to come from? Also, in your expected output you don't use the `exit_to` value.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample = """<node id="146994270" version="12" timestamp="2016-09-13T14:08:42Z" lat="50.4589679" lon="18.2668417">
<tag k="name" v="Kędzierzyn-Koźle"/>
<tag k="highway" v="motorway_junction"/>
<tag k="milestone" v="272"/> 
</node>"""

nodes = BeautifulSoup(sample, "html.parser").find_all("node")

speed, dir_type, direction = 60, 1, 1
for idx, node in enumerate(nodes):
    _id, lat, lon = node["id"], node["lat"], node["lon"]
    name, exit_to, milestone = [v["v"] for v in node.find_all("tag")]

    template_left = f"{idx},{lon},{lat},{_id},{speed},{dir_type},{direction}"
    template_right = f"${_id}='|{milestone}| {name}'"

    print(f"{template_left} // {template_right}")
```

This prints:

```
0,18.2668417,50.4589679,146994270,60,1,1 // $146994270='|272| Kędzierzyn-Koźle'
```

Comment: I have one another example with "exit_to". exit_to is not a obligation.

Comment: And how would the expected output look like with the `exit_to` value?

Comment: And how do you want to deal with the output if there's no `milestone` or `exit_to` values?

Comment: "And how do you want to deal with the output if there's no milestone or exit_to values?"
Empty place, nothing. If the information is not present, there is nothing on the shield. Imagin a highway sign: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dmotorway_junction